# Applying a classification pipeline to a subset of the dataset

Tags: python, pandas, svm

I'm working with classifications on short text snippets (1-3 sentences). Topic-wise, the dataset contains texts on plants, animals and unrelated stuff. First, I'm using a classifier (linear SVM) to tag each snippet's category (svm_gen: 0 - unrelated, 1 - plants, 2 - animals). Works without problems.

Now each category has sub-categories which I would also like to classify with an own algorithm for each. Say, for plant (svm_plant: 0 - other, 1 - sow, 2 - grow, 3 - harvest) and for animals (svm_animal: 0 - other, 1 - feed, 2 - pet, 3 - play). How can I apply the respective pipelines selectively to the pre-clssified variables without splitting and then appending again the dataset?

As said before, I can split the dataset based on the pre-classification, apply the second round of classifiers on the new pandas Dataframes and then append them back together. Is there a better way?

```
svm_gen = Pipeline([( ... )])
svm_gen.fit()
df_complete['Topic'] = svm_gen.predict(df_complete['Text'])

# write all texts concerning animals into a new df to apply the respective SVM
df_plant = df_complete[df_complete.Topic == 1]

# same for animals

# categories both individually for the sub-categories

# glue them back together

df_final = df_plant.append(df_animals, ingnore_index = True)
```

Basically, I would like to have a final dataset (pandas dataframe) containing the column 'Text', the column 'Topic' and then the column 'sub-Topic'. The latter was classified selectively based on which category the text falls into in the first round of classification. Somewhat like:

```
df_complete.loc[df_complete['Topic'] == 1, 'sub_Topic'] = svm_plant.predict['Text']
df_complete.loc[df_complete['Topic'] == 2, 'sub_Topic'] = svm_animals.predict['Text']
df_complete.loc[df_complete['Topic'] == 0, 'sub_Topic'] = 'n/a'
```

Answer (score 0):

short answer **NO**

From [scikit docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#pipeline)

> Pipeline can be used to chain multiple estimators into one....

and

> All estimators in a pipeline, except the last one, must be
>   transformers (i.e. must have a transform method). The last estimator
>   may be any type (transformer, classifier, etc.).

So you can have only one classifier at the end of the pipeline and scikit pipeline is sequential. You have to train different classifiers (reusing the same pipleline) with different datasets and manually select them.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am familiar with the general use of pipeline and classifiers - it is more a pandas Dataframe question than a sk-learn question. The question was more whether I can restrict to which subset of the dataset (i.e. row 0-5 but not 6-10) the classifier will be applied.